# pandas.algos v0.14 ValueError:float nan to int

Tags: python, pandas

Just upgraded from `0.10` to `0.14`, getting a floatNaN to int error.

> File "generated.pyx", line 104, in pandas.algos.ensure_int64 (pandas/algos.c:46822)
>   File "generated.pyx", line 109, in pandas.algos.ensure_int64 (pandas/algos.c:46727)
>   ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

the following code worked in `0.10`:

```
dt=dt.drop(['unneeded, cols'])
dt['time'] = pd.to_datetime( dt['time'] )
dt2 = dt.reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates(['combos','of','columns'])
dt2 = dt2.set_index(['all the columns'])
dt2 = dt2.unstack()
dt2.columns = dt2.columns.droplevel(0)
dt2.reset_index()
...
```

I then needed to use a .iloc, and decided to upgrade

** the error occurs at unstack()

Should I uninstall pandas and upgrade to say `0.12`, or is there something I am doing wrong here in terms of the new pandas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the entire stack trace? (if you could find a small repoducible example that'd be great)

Comment: pls show ``dt.info()`` (at the very beginning)